# Can "myself" be used as emphasis in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Can *myself* be used as emphasis in the following sentence, or is another word preferable (e.g. *also*, *too*)?

> I myself found difficult to believe to what she was saying, but then she gave me the proof.

Is there any difference between saying *I myself found difficult to believe it*, *I am the first who found difficult to believe it*, and *I also found difficult to believe it*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use **myself** for emphasis in that sentence. What it emphasizes it **your incredulity**. It means "**Even I** found it difficult to believe what she was saying, but then she gave me the proof."

"I myself found difficult to believe it." is ungrammatical and meaningless. It has to be "I myself found it difficult to believe." or "It was difficult for me to believe it".

Notice the two *it*s. They serve different functions in this sentence.

"I am the first who found difficult to believe." is ungrammatical and meaningless. It has to be "I am the first who found it difficult to believe." This doesn't mean "I myself found it difficult to believe." It means that everyone else found it easy to believe.

"I also found difficult to believe it." is ungrammatical and meaningless. It has to be "I also found it difficult to believe." That means that everybody else found it difficult to believe.

Comment: Talking with somebody who doesn't believe her, can I say "I was the first who didn't believe what she said, but then she gave me the proof." and get a similar meaning _myself_ would give to the sentence? (In my example, I used "I am the first" which is probably not correct.) In the sentence I quoted (the longer one), should I change the position of _difficult_ (e.g. putting it before the comma), or is that word in the right position?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "I was the first who didn't believe what she said,..." implies that after you found it difficult, then others found it difficult & wanted to see the proof. Maybe others won't agree with my interpretation here, but the new syntax creates a different feeling in my mind. No, it doesn't cause the S to mean "I myself found it difficult..." Writing "I myself found to believe what she was saying difficult,..." is awkward to my ear; "I myself found it difficult to believe what she was saying,..." sounds natural to me.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Is "I myself can do nothing." formal? Shouldn't it better be like "I by myself can do nothing."? Do these two sentences have different meaning?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli I think those two sentences have a slightly different meaning, but I am the user who asked the question (not posted this answer), so you should ask to somebody else, or ask a new question if somebody didn't ask it already.

Comment: For example, _I myself_ is just a way to put emphasis on me, while _I by myself_ could mean _I alone_, as in _Alone, I cannot do anything._